# How to write a VBA function whose return value is recognized as a date by Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, datetime

I wrote the following test function in MS Excel 2002:

```
Function someDate() As Date
    someDate = Now()
End Function
```

Then I use the function in a cell, like this `=someDate()`. But the value is shown as a floating point number.
However, if I do this `=now()`, the cell value is shown as a date as expected.

How can I write a function that returns a date and Excel automatically recognize the value as a date?

Comment: If you want the cell to look like a date, you must format it as a date.  As TheSilkCode says: Excel stores dates as numbers.  The Integer part is days since 1/1/1900.  The fraction part is (SecondsSinceMidnight)/(SecondsInDay).  It is the NumberFormat for a cell that determines how that number is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edited** to show a possible handling of OS date format

you could leave your function as it is and add this code in `ThisWorkbook` code pane:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim dateSeparator As String

    dateSeparator = Application.International(xlDateSeparator) '<--| retrieve OS date separator
    For Each cell In Target
        If cell.Formula = "=someDate()" Then
            Select Case Application.International(xlDateOrder) '<--| query OS date format
                Case 0
                    cell.NumberFormat = "mm" & dateSeparator & "dd" & dateSeparator & "yyyy"
                Case 1
                    cell.NumberFormat = "dd" & dateSeparator & "mm" & dateSeparator & "yyyy"
                Case 2
                    cell.NumberFormat = "yyyy" & dateSeparator & "mm" & dateSeparator & "dd"
            End Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can this technique work if the function receives parameters?

Comment: In that case you can code " If Left(cell.Formula,10)="=someDate(" Then..."

Comment: @GetFree, did you get through it?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I fear this could interfere with the user's custom format choice for a given cell. Also, it won't honor the OS date format settings.

Comment: my answer solves your _original_ question, that didn't mention neither any user's custom nor OS date format issue. anyhow see edited answer to show you a possible handling for OS date format. while as to "user's custom format choice" you can act in a similar way by checking `cell.NumberFormat` value

Comment: @GetFree, did you finally get through it?

Comment: Unfortunately the SheetChange event is supported only in Excel 2010 an later, so I can't use it.

Comment: [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm) and [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) they say that events have been introduced from Excel 97

Comment: Then there must be some other problem. I tried on Excel 2002 and the `Workbook_SheetChange` function is never called. Now I tried in Excel 2010 and again the function is never called, no matter how many times I modify cell values. I even added the line `Debug.Print "Workbook_SheetChange"` to know for sure if the function is being called, but I get no message in the immediate window.

Comment: It's working now. I read your answer again. I missed the part **add this code in ThisWorkbook code pane**

Comment: Fine. Good coding!

Answer (score 1):

Not possible AFAIK, just write some code to make Excel interpret that cell as a Date,

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
```

Though I'm sure you knew that:)

Other ways of forcing a date format are to make the cell the result of a formula where an operand is also a date, so you could have `0` formatted as a date and add to your cell and it would be a date though this is so kludgy that most Excel programmer resile to formatting the cell with some VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores dates as numbers, so what you are seeing is the date in its numerical format- at the end of whatever you are trying to do, whether that's in a macro or outputting to a cell, just convert back to the date format you prefer at the end using Format for VBA and TEXT for Excel.

Hope this helps,
TheSilkCode

Comment: That would return a string. I need a date so I can perform date operations without converting from string to date back and forth all the time.

Comment: The number is a date- treat it as such (compare it to dates, use date functions, etc.) and you will have no problems.